# Is there a way to set up a key combination to spawn a new urxvt window?

Tags: linux, terminal, urxvt

I'm running urxvt and would like to create a new urxvt window without having to run the command explicitly or use an external launcher.

Is there a way to set something up for this to work as, for example, gnome-terminal or Xfce terminal, where I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to do so?

Comment: You could simply set a shortcut on your desktop manager to run `urxvt`.

Comment: That's what I'll end up doing if I can't find an answer, but I use different environments in different boxes and would like to share a configuration for urxvt only.

Comment: which DE are you using?

Comment: Unity on some boxes, XFCE on others, WindowMaker on others.